# How to specify a column name and data item in Blueprism?

Tags: c#, sql, vbscript, automation, robotics

I'm using Blueprism to work with SQL queries and in my query, the column name is referenced like this `[columnName]` which is the right way and data items are referenced this way `[dataItem]`.

For example, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `[columnName] = [dataItem]`"

The problem with the above is that the BluePrism reads both as columns and outputs an error saying dataItem is not a column name. How do I reference a data item in a query? Blueprism uses C#/VB Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to append the sql query and the variable.

`"SELECT * FROM [Customer Details] WHERE [Name] ='" & [Test] &  "' "`